# Using cURL in Android Studio (vultr API)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, curl, server

I want to set up an android app in Android studio where a user sends and stores information on their own server. I understand CURL has to be used in order to accomplish this. I currently own a vultr server which I would like to access via my app, but do not know how to properly implement curl within the main Java code in order to do so. Please help :D

> according to vultr API, curl request is implemented as so:

```
curl -H 'API-Key: YOURKEY' --data "SUBID=12345" "https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/start"
```

> the button I would like to use to send information

```
 Button generatebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generatebutton);
    generatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

        }
    });
```

> vultr API I am using: https://www.vultr.com/api/

The next thing I need to accomplish is picking photos to upload to the server. If you have the time to answer this as well, I would appreciate that a lot :)

Happy coding!